# Filter by row name and column name in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have the following challenge that i couldnt solve by my selfe.
The data is in a matrix style so the rows have names as well as the cols...
Here is an example:

[image]

| Product | Tool1 | Tool2 | Tool3 | Tool4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | Yes | No | Yes | No |
| P2 | Yes | Yes | No | No |
| P3 | Yes | No | No | Yes |
| P4 | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

So i have two Cells where in the first one the user can name a product and in the second one name a tool.
I want to have a result looking like these (Product = P4, Tool = Tool3:)

[image]

| Product | Tool3 |
| --- | --- |
| P4 | Yes |

I tried around with the FILTER function but couldnt find a way to choose both the right column and the right Product.
Thank you very much for your time and help!
Cheers!

Comment: Classic INDEX/MATCH/MATCH is possible too: `=INDEX(B2:E5,MATCH(G2,A2:A5,0),MATCH(H1,B1:E1,0))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try one of the following, as per your `Excel Versions`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(G2,A2:A5,FILTER(B2:E5,H1=B1:E1))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=CONCAT(REPT(B2:E5,G2&"|"&I1=A2:A5&"|"&B1:E1))
```

---